# Enable next select directly after, not all

Tags: jquery, html

I have these selection elements along. All I want to do, is have the the next two after the first disabled. When the first one has been selected, then only enable the next ONE directly after the selection that was made.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.model-select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.year-select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('select').change(function(){
   $('.carSelect').next().attr('disabled','');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="make-list" id="make-list">
                        <div class="make-wrap">
                            <select class="carSelect make-select">
                                <option>Make</option>
                                <option data-tag="audi" data-index="0">Audi</option>
                                <option data-tag="bmw" data-index="1">BMW</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="model-wrap">
                            <select class="carSelect model-select">
                                <option>Model</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="year-wrap">
                            <select class="carSelect year-select">
                                <option>Year</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Each attempt I have made removes the disable from both selections after, but this is not what is needed. Only the one directly after.

Comment: are you saying step by step? once first is select, enable the other 2? or first select, enable 2nd, if 2nd select, enable 3rd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if not step by step, select 1st and enable all then

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $('.carSelect').closest('div').next().find('select').prop('disabled',false);
});
```

if step by step enable then(select 1st, enable 2nd, select 2nd, enable 3rd)

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $(this).closest('div').next().find('select').prop('disabled',false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add data-id to select, and use them to enable them.
This way, even if your HTML structure changes, code will remain the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.model-select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.year-select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('select').change(function(){
   $("select[data-id='"+($(this).data("id")+1)+"']").prop("disabled",'')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="make-list" id="make-list">
                        <div class="make-wrap">
                            <select class="carSelect make-select" data-id="0">
                                <option>Make</option>
                                <option data-tag="audi" data-index="0">Audi</option>
                                <option data-tag="bmw" data-index="1">BMW</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="model-wrap">
                            <select class="carSelect model-select" data-id="1">
                                <option>Model</option>
                                <option data-tag="A57" data-index="0">Audi</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="year-wrap">
                            <select class="carSelect year-select"  data-id="2">
                                <option>Year</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```